# Drawing Multiple Sprites with Different Properties in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

I'm writing a bit of code where I animate a hundred copies of the same sprite onto the screen by creating a sprite class. I want the sprites, an animation of four-ring interlocking rings spinning within each other, to be drawn at a certain height, drop down on the screen, and bounce like a ball, with each bounce being progressively less until it they stop completely. I have managed to get this part done; however, I can't seem to find a way to randomize the acceleration and animation speed of each different sprite. Can someone provide some suggestions to my code?

Game 1.cs

```
namespace lab_6
  {

   public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
   {
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    Sprite rings;


    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);


        Texture2D rings_texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Images/threerings");

        //animation
        Point frameSize = new Point(75, 75);
        Point currentFrame = new Point(0, 0);
        Point sheetSize = new Point(6, 8);
        int millisecondsPerFrame = 50;
    rings = new Sprite(rings_texture, ringsPos,
            frameSize, 0, currentFrame, sheetSize, ringsSpeed, millisecondsPerFrame);
    }



    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }


    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();
        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        rings.Update(gameTime, Window.ClientBounds);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }


    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spriteBatch.Begin();

        rings.Draw(gameTime, spriteBatch);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
   }
}
```

Sprite.cs

```
namespace lab_6
{
    public class Sprite
    {
    //basics
    protected Texture2D rings;
    protected Vector2 ringsPos = new Vector2(0,0);
    protected Color tint = Color.White;
    protected Vector2 ringsSpeed = new Vector2(0,0);
    protected Vector2 ringsAccel = new Vector2(0, 1);

    //animation
    protected Point frameSize = new Point(75,75);
    protected Point currentFrame = new Point(0, 0);
    protected Point sheetSize = new Point(6,8);

    //animation timing
    protected int timeSinceLastFrame = 0;
    protected int millisecondsPerFrame = 50;
    const int defaultMillisecondsPerFrame = 16;

    //bounding box offset
    protected int collisionOffset;

    Random r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);

    public Sprite(Texture2D rings, Vector2 ringsPos, Point frameSize,
                    int collisionOffset, Point currentFrame, Point sheetSize, Vector2 ringsSpeed,
                    int millisecondsPerFrame)
    {
        this.rings = rings;
        this.ringsPos = ringsPos;
        this.frameSize = frameSize;
        this.collisionOffset = collisionOffset;
        this.currentFrame = currentFrame;
        this.sheetSize = sheetSize;
        this.ringsSpeed = ringsSpeed;
        this.millisecondsPerFrame = millisecondsPerFrame;
    }




    public virtual void Update(GameTime gameTime, Rectangle clientBounds)
    {


        int maxY = (600 - frameSize.Y );
        ringsAccel.Y += (byte)r.Next((1 / 10), 1);
        ringsSpeed.Y += ringsAccel.Y;
        ringsPos.Y += ringsSpeed.Y;


        if (ringsPos.Y > maxY)
        {
            ringsSpeed *= -0.8f;
            ringsPos.Y = maxY;
        }

        //Update animation frame
        millisecondsPerFrame = 50;
        millisecondsPerFrame *= ((byte)r.Next(1, 10));

        timeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
        if (timeSinceLastFrame > millisecondsPerFrame)
        {
            timeSinceLastFrame = 0;
            ++currentFrame.X;
            if (currentFrame.X >= sheetSize.X)
            {
                currentFrame.X = 0;
                ++currentFrame.Y;
                if (currentFrame.Y >= sheetSize.Y)
                    currentFrame.Y = 0;
            }
        }

    }



    public virtual void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; )
        {

           Vector2 newPos = ringsPos + new Vector2((10 * i), (1 * (byte)r.Next((1/10), 1)));
            spriteBatch.Draw(rings, newPos,
                new Rectangle(currentFrame.X * frameSize.X, 
                currentFrame.Y * frameSize.Y,
                frameSize.X, frameSize.Y),
                tint, 0, Vector2.Zero, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
            i++;
            r = new Random(DateTime.Now.Second);
        }
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the constructor for ringSpeed and ringAccel to the constructor and randomize them there.

Comment: Please be more specific about your problem.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that each of the 100 sprites has a different acceleration so when they bounce, they do so at a different speed. I'm also trying to randomize the variable `millisecondsPerFrame` to give the sprites random animation speeds also. I just am not sure how to do this. And I'm not entirely sure if I follow your suggestion... Do I move the constructor within the `Sprite.cs` file or the `Game 1.cs` file?

Comment: The one in Sprite.cs

Comment: But _where_ within Sprite.cs?

Comment: Okay, move the part that sets acceleration and speed in Sprite.cs to the constructor, and set it to random there, now every time a Sprite is created, those get randomized